# how to adjust multiple one-line textbox?

Tags: html

I'm trying to adjust three one-line text box , any solutions ? 
thanks in advance^^

```
 <form action="" method="">
First Name:<input type="text" name="fname">
    <br>
Middle Name:<input type="text" name="midname">`enter code here`
    <br>
Last Name:<input type="text" name="lname">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi @toqa-yousri, what adjustments are you trying to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED:**
Thanks for your clarification. This is only one possible way of many, but you could use "position" in the inline styles.

```
<form action="" method="">
<!-- use position with inline styles -->
<div style="width: 360px">
  <div style="font-size: 29px; position: relative;">
      First Name:<input type="text" name="fname" style="margin-left: 16px; position: absolute; right: 0; top: 20%;">
  </div>
      <br>
  <div style="font-size: 29px; position: relative;">
      Middle Name:<input type="text" name="midname" style="margin-left: 16px; position: absolute; right: 0; top: 20%;">
  </div>
      <br>
  <div style="font-size: 29px; position: relative;">
      Last Name:<input type="text" name="lname" style="margin-left: 16px; position: absolute; right: 0; top: 20%;">
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Result can be viewed here:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G6IG3ZCUI8MW

Comment: @the_legitDM thank you very much , that's what i mean^^